# Passando uma lista de objetos para um dicionário em python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu tenho uma lista de objetos:

`lista_objetos = ['acarreta', 'afeta', 'alavancagem', 'apropriadas', 'arvore', 'avaliacao']`

cada objeto guarda informações, entre essas informações a própria palavra, Ex: `afeta.palavra` é igual `"afeta"`.

Meu objetivo é enumerar esses objetos da seguinte forma:

```
1 - acarreta
2 - afeta
3 - alavancagem
4 - apropriadas
5 - arvore
6 - avaliacao
```

Estou tentando colocar essas informações numa estrutura de **dicionário**, desta forma a seguir, porém não está funcionando, o que estou fazendo de errado....

```
dic = {}

for objeto in lista_objeto:
    cont = 1
    dic[cont] = objeto.palavra
    cont += 1
```

ele adiciona um item ao dic e para.. está errado essa forma de adicionar elementos no dic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, está errado. Perceba que você está definindo `cont = 1` dentro do seu laço de repetição, então no início de cada iteração, o valor de `cont` volta a ser 1, sempre adicionando o objeto na mesma chave do dicionário.

Você poderia apenas retirar essa inicialização do laço `for`:

```
lista_objetos = ['acarreta', 'afeta', 'alavancagem', 'apropriadas', 'arvore', 'avaliacao']
dic = {}

cont = 1
for objeto in lista_objetos:
    dic[cont] = objeto #objeto.palavra
    cont += 1

print(dic)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/HQbGME) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/Nwqs/0)</sup>

Assim a saída seria:

```
{1: 'acarreta', 2: 'afeta', 3: 'alavancagem', 4: 'apropriadas', 5: 'arvore', 6: 'avaliacao'}
```

Ou, da forma mais *pythonica*, você pode utilizar a função `enumerate`:

```
lista_objetos = ['acarreta', 'afeta', 'alavancagem', 'apropriadas', 'arvore', 'avaliacao']
dic = {}

for chave, objeto in enumerate(lista_objetos):
    dic[chave] = objeto

print(dic)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/BeLKPN) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/Nwqv/0)</sup>

Produzindo a saída:

```
{0: 'acarreta', 1: 'afeta', 2: 'alavancagem', 3: 'apropriadas', 4: 'arvore', 5: 'avaliacao'}
```

Ou ainda, sem utilizar o laço de repetição, você pode utilizar a função `zip` em conjunto com a função `range`:

```
dic = dict( zip(range(len(lista_objetos)), lista_objetos) )
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/0dkRbD) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/Nwr9/0)</sup>

Produzindo a saída:

```
{0: 'acarreta', 1: 'afeta', 2: 'alavancagem', 3: 'apropriadas', 4: 'arvore', 5: 'avaliacao'}
```

Comment: caramba... nem tinha percebido isso, esse cont = 1 dentro do laço que estava me atrapalhando..  obrigado @andersoncarloswoss